# Change TextColor

Tags: c#

When I am trying to change color of my Label, my compiler shows me an error, why ?
How I can resolve this ? Thank you.

Error: does not contain a definition for 'TextColor' and no extension method 'TextColor' accepting a first argument of type 'H_M.Form1 has been found.

Code:

```
private void UAVON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

> my compiler shows me an error, why ?

Well, you are not referring to your label.`this` refers to your current Form instance.You need to access your label by it's name and like `labelName.Property = something`, and there is no `TextColor` property on label if you are using WinForms, I think you are looking for [`ForeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code for this should be

```
this.labelname.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```